# when try to overriding the nserror cant get anything

Tags: objective-c

i want do base on the nserror info,create a new instance of nserror,but seem is not work at all

```
    - (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError * *)outError 
{

    NSError *breakError = nil;

    todoItems = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:NULL error:&breakError]; 
    if (todoItems == nil){
        NSString *desc = NSLocalizedString(@"Can't do it!", @"");
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : desc };
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.pink.test" code:3084 userInfo:userInfo];
        return NO;
    }


    // Insert code here to read your document from the given data of the specified type. If outError != NULL, ensure that you create and set an appropriate error when returning NO.
    // You can also choose to override -readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error: or -readFromURL:ofType:error: instead.
    // If you override either of these, you should also override -isEntireFileLoaded to return NO if the contents are lazily loaded.
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"UnimplementedMethod" reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is unimplemented", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)] userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
    return YES;
}
```

i always only can get the default dialog message,even i not pass the nserror back
[image]

---

i sorry it if not clear,here is a demo for what i repeat what happen of mine.

[image][image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in your code, do you even hit that function?  I suspect that your problem is outside of the code you have posted above, as the error says "document could not be *opened*".

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes,it was into the function,only if I return no,so it will cause the error.

Comment: Your issue is unclear. In the code you posted, what happens? Which code is executed and what is your actual problem? There is the dialog message coming from?

Comment: BTW - You must check to see if `outError` is non-nil before you attempt to dereference the pointer.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I not make that clear,this is a simplest coca document application,and I want when the file format is not right,I can throw back my own *outError information,but I can't get it the custom NSError message,that's really buggy me.

Comment: You didn't answer my question at all. When you run the code in your question using the debugger, what actually happens? What is the code path?

Comment: @rmaddy you are right,I will later rewrite the question at all,I sorry,I will learn how to describe a question as well as I can.thank you pointer this to me.

Comment: Seems weird -- the code either returns an error or throws an exception.  Why even bother calling it?

Answer (score 1):

加油了. 你想陈述的问题,跟别人看到的可能不一样.

If you have a error output in that function , there is no need to throw exception.

Here is a example making `nserror` from kxsmb:

```
static NSError * mkKxSMBError(KxSMBError error, NSString *format, ...)
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = nil;
    NSString *reason = nil;

    if (format) {

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        reason = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
        va_end(args);
    }

    if (reason) {

        userInfo = @{
                     NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : KxSMBErrorMessage(error),
                     NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : reason
                     };

    } else {

        userInfo = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : KxSMBErrorMessage(error) };
    }

    return [NSError errorWithDomain:KxSMBErrorDomain
                               code:error
                           userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: 好一个用汉语的同胞!在这外国的岛屿上,真荣幸!

Comment: anyway,i update some photos,hope that be some clear,i just want write a custom outError for the return of objc..just for fun

Answer (score 0):

it's done,turn out it's only can be use system define error,not can be custom,it means only can be errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain and a valid code

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError * *)outError
{
    if (*outError == nil){
        NSString *desc = NSLocalizedString(@"Can't do it!", @"");
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : desc };
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:3840 userInfo:userInfo];
    }

    return NO;
```

thank for the all help.